# AngularJS to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I must be missing something... because I'm really a noob at this.

I have this angularjs data:

```
$scope.todoList = [
      { text: 'Check me out' },
      { text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, possit denique oportere at his, etiam corpora deseruisse te pro' },
      { text: 'Ex has semper alterum, expetenda dignissim' },
    ];
```

And I wanted to put it in a mysql table instead. I created the table and then tried to get table data:

JS:

```
$http({method:'POST',url:'process.php'})
          .then(
            function successCallback(response) { $scope.todoList = response.data;}, 
            function errorCallback(response) {$scope.todoList = "ERROR!";});
```

PHP:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * from `todolist`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array("text" => $row['text']);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

When I manually try the PHP the output is:

```
[{"text":"Check me out"},{"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, possit denique oportere at his, etiam corpora deseruisse te pro"},{"text":"Ex has semper alterum, expetenda dignissim"}]
```

Does someone know where the problem is?

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Your response data type is not [valid json data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), and assigns response-string without parsing to `$scope.todoList`; use `JSON.parse(response.data)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about **reading and assigning value of response data**; so I've commented:

> Your response data type is not [valid json data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), and assigns response-string without parsing to `$scope.todoList`; use `JSON.parse(response.data)`

and suggest these topics (maybe helpful):

- [working with JSON data array from Ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985363/working-with-json-data-array-from-ajax-response)
- [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

If you have problem with **Updating after AJAX call**:

- [how can refresh my scope after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397360/how-can-refresh-my-scope-after-ajax-call)
- [Angular controller scope not updating after jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127709/angular-controller-scope-not-updating-after-jquery-ajax-call)

more related to this problem:

- [How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)

---

If your problem is none of these topics, let us know to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried JSON.parse(response.data) but no success.
I'll try to elaborate a bit more:

This code worked fine:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1));
  return colors[i];
}

$scope.todoList = [
  { text: 'Check me out' },
  { text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, possit denique oportere at his, etiam corpora deseruisse te pro' },
  { text: 'Ex has semper alterum, expetenda dignissim' },
];

$scope.todoList.forEach(function(item) {
  item.color = getRandomColor();
});
```

But now this one gives an error in console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1));
  return colors[i];
}

$http({method:'POST',url:'process.php',data:{function: "todolist"}})
          .then(
            function successCallback(response) {$scope.todoList = response.data;}, 
            function errorCallback(response) {console.log("ERROR!");});

$scope.todoList.forEach(function(item) {
  item.color = getRandomColor();
});
```

It seems like it doesn't wait for the ajax results... But I don't really know.

SOLVED putting foreach function inside successCallback function.

Comment: Solved putting the forEach function inside the successCallback. Thanks everyone!

Comment: good edit and [How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)